Consistency of vertex_descriptor in dijkstra_shortest_paths()
In BGL introductory example,
using namespace boost;

  int main(int,char*[])
  {
    // create a typedef for the Graph type
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS> Graph;

    // Make convenient labels for the vertices
    enum { A, B, C, D, E, N };
    const int num_vertices = N;
    const char* name = "ABCDE";

    // writing out the edges in the graph
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
    Edge edge_array[] =
    { Edge(A,B), Edge(A,D), Edge(C,A), Edge(D,C),
      Edge(C,E), Edge(B,D), Edge(D,E) };
    const int num_edges = sizeof(edge_array)/sizeof(edge_array[0]);

    // declare a graph object
    Graph g(num_vertices);

    // add the edges to the graph object
    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; ++i)
      add_edge(edge_array[i].first, edge_array[i].second, g);
    ...
    return 0;
  }

The vertices are referred as integer indices enum {a,B,C,D,E,N}.
In a similar scenario, without bundled vertex property (full code at the end):
    struct Edge
    {
      int source;
      int target;
      float weight;
    };

    using Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,Edge>;
    using GraphTraits=boost::graph_traits<Graph>;
    using VertexDescriptor=GraphTraits::vertex_iterator;

    Graph graph(5); // 5 vertices

    VertexDescriptor v=boost::vertex(1,graph);


The definition of VertexDescriptor v fails to compile.
My IDE traced to the definition in adjacency_list.hpp:
template < class Graph, class Config, class Base >
inline typename Config::vertex_descriptor vertex(
    typename Config::vertices_size_type n,
    const vec_adj_list_impl< Graph, Config, Base >&)
{
    return n;
}


To populate the graph, I found that using VertexDescriptor
    for(auto const &e:edges)
    {
      boost::add_edge(boost::vertex(e.source,graph),boost::vertex(e.target,graph),e,graph);
    }

or int
    for(auto const &e:edges)
    {
      boost::add_edge(e.source,e.target,e,graph);
    }

both can populate the graph.
From dijkstra_shortest_paths() doc

OUT: predecessor_map(PredecessorMap p_map)
The predecessor map records the edges in the shortest path tree, the tree computed by the traversal of the graph. Upon completion of the algorithm, the edges (p[u],u) for all u in V are in the tree. The shortest path from vertex s to each vertex v in the graph consists of the vertices v, p[v], p[p[v]], and so on until s is reached, in reverse order. The tree is not guaranteed to be a minimum spanning tree. If p[u] = u then u is either the source vertex or a vertex that is not reachable from the source. The PredecessorMap type must be a Read/Write Property Map whose key and value types are the same as the vertex descriptor type of the graph.

It said "The PredecessorMap type must be a Read/Write Property Map whose key and value types are the same as the vertex descriptor type of the graph."
However, if I construct PredecessorMap using std::vector<VertexDescriptor>, the code failed to compile. I have to use std::vector<int> to construct it instead.
Full code:
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<format>
#include<map>
#include<deque>
#include<memory>
#include<functional>
#include<cassert>

#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include<boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
//#include<boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include<boost/pending/queue.hpp>
#include<boost/heap/priority_queue.hpp>
#include<boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

  void test003()
  {
    std::cout << "test003: " << std::endl;

    struct Edge
    {
      int source;
      int target;
      float weight;
    };

    using Graph=boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,Edge>;
    using GraphTraits=boost::graph_traits<Graph>;
    using VertexDescriptor=GraphTraits::vertex_iterator;
    using EdgeDescriptor=GraphTraits::edge_descriptor;


    Graph graph(5); // 5 vertices
    std::vector<Edge> edges{{.source=0,.target=1,.weight=10.0},
                            {.source=1,.target=2,.weight=1.1},
                            {.source=2,.target=3,.weight=3.4},
                            {.source=3,.target=0,.weight=8.0},
                            {.source=2,.target=2,.weight=0.5},
                            {.source=1,.target=3,.weight=3.3},
                            {.source=0,.target=0,.weight=2.2},
                            {.source=3,.target=2,.weight=0.7},
                            {.source=2,.target=0,.weight=5.2}};

    // different type! won't compile.
    //VertexDescriptor v=boost::vertex(1,graph);

    for(auto const &e:edges)
    {
      //boost::add_edge(boost::vertex(e.source,graph),boost::vertex(e.target,graph),e,graph);
      boost::add_edge(e.source,e.target,e,graph);
    }

    auto weightMap=boost::get(&Edge::weight,graph);
    auto vertexIndexMap=boost::get(boost::vertex_index,graph);
    std::vector<float> distances(boost::num_vertices(graph));

    // won't compile if use VertexDescriptor.
    //std::vector<VertexDescriptor> predecessors(boost::num_vertices(graph));
    std::vector<int> predecessors(boost::num_vertices(graph));

    auto distanceMap=boost::make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(),vertexIndexMap);
    auto predecessorMap=boost::predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.begin(),vertexIndexMap));

    //VertexDescriptor startingVertex=boost::vertex(1,graph);
    int startingVertex=1;
    boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(graph,
                                   boost::vertex(startingVertex,graph),
                                   boost::weight_map(get(&Edge::weight,graph))
                                     .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(),get(boost::vertex_index, graph)))
                                     .predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.begin(),get(boost::vertex_index,graph))));

    std::cout<<"The shortest paths:"<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<boost::num_vertices(graph);++i)
    {
      if(i==startingVertex)
        continue;
      std::cout<<"From "<<startingVertex<<" to "<<i<<" is "<<distances[i]<<": ";
      if(i==predecessors[i])
      {
        std::cout<<"No route."<<std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout<<i<<" -> ";
        for(auto p=predecessors[i];p<predecessors.size() && p!=predecessors[p] && p!=startingVertex;p=predecessors[p])
        {
          std::cout<<p<<" -> ";
        }
        std::cout<<startingVertex<<std::endl;
      }
    }

    std::cout << "test003: done." << std::endl;
  }

int main()
{
  test003();
  return 0;
}


Just would like to have it clarified the usage of vertex_descriptor. It seems I still confused with something... Is it interchangeable with graph_traits::vertex_descripitor with integral types, at least for vecS selector? It seems yes and no...

You mistyped vertex_descriptor as vertex_iterator.
That's basically all there was to it.
Regardless, there's room for simplifications, mostly by removal of unused things:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void test003() {
    std::cout << "test003: " << std::endl;

    using Weight = float;
    struct Edge { Weight weight; };

    using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, Edge>;
    using V = G::vertex_descriptor;

    G graph(5); // 5 vertices

    [[maybe_unused]] V v = boost::vertex(1, graph);

    for (auto const& [source, target, weight] : //
         {std::tuple{0u, 1u, 10.0f}, {1, 2, 1.1}, {2, 3, 3.4}, {3, 0, 8.0},
          {2, 2, 0.5}, {1, 3, 3.3}, {0, 0, 2.2}, {3, 2, 0.7}, {2, 0, 5.2}})
    {
        add_edge(source, target, {weight}, graph);
    }

    std::vector<Weight> distances(num_vertices(graph));
    std::vector<V>      predecessors(num_vertices(graph));

    V start = vertex(1, graph);
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(graph, start,
                            weight_map(get(&Edge::weight, graph))
                                .distance_map(distances.data())
                                .predecessor_map(predecessors.data()));

    std::cout << "The shortest paths:" << std::endl;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(graph))) {
        if (v == start)
            continue;
        std::cout << "From " << start << " to " << v << " is " << distances[v] << ": ";

        if (v == predecessors[v]) {
            std::cout << "No route." << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << v << " -> ";
            for (auto p = predecessors[v];                                      //
                 p < predecessors.size() && p != predecessors[p] && p != start; //
                 p = predecessors[p])
                std::cout << p << " -> ";

            std::cout << start << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "test003: done." << std::endl;
}

int main() { test003(); }

Non-vecS vertex storage
Of course, indirection through an index map could be important for some graph models:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Weight = float;
struct Edge {
    Weight weight;
};

template <typename Graph, typename V = Graph::vertex_descriptor>
void do_the_thing(Graph const& graph, V start) {
    auto const N = num_vertices(graph);
    std::map<V, unsigned> temp_map;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(graph)))
        temp_map[v] = temp_map.size();

    std::vector<Weight> distances(N);
    std::vector<V>      predecessors(N);

    auto vidx = boost::make_assoc_property_map(temp_map);
    auto wmap = get(&Edge::weight, graph);
    auto dmap = make_safe_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), distances.size(), vidx, Weight{});
    auto pmap =
        make_safe_iterator_property_map(predecessors.begin(), distances.size(), vidx, graph.null_vertex());

    dijkstra_shortest_paths( //
        graph, start, weight_map(wmap).distance_map(dmap).predecessor_map(pmap).vertex_index_map(vidx));

    std::cout << "The shortest paths:" << std::endl;
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(graph))) {
        if (v == start)
            continue;
        auto i = vidx[v];
        std::cout << "From " << vidx[start] << " to " << i << " is " << distances[i] << ": ";

        if (v == predecessors[i]) {
            std::cout << "No route." << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << vidx[v] << " -> ";
            for (V cur = v, p = predecessors[i]; cur != p && p != start;) {
                std::cout << vidx[cur] << " -> ";
                cur = p;
                p   = predecessors[vidx[cur]];
            }

            std::cout << vidx[start] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void test003() {
    std::cout << "test003: " << std::endl;

    using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS /*NOTE*/, //
                                    boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, Edge>;

    G graph;
    std::array<G::vertex_descriptor, 5> vmap = {};
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 5; ++i)
        vmap[i] = add_vertex(graph);

    for (auto const& [source, target, weight] : //
         {std::tuple{0u, 1u, 10.0f}, {1, 2, 1.1}, {2, 3, 3.4}, {3, 0, 8.0},
          {2, 2, 0.5}, {1, 3, 3.3}, {0, 0, 2.2}, {3, 2, 0.7}, {2, 0, 5.2}})
        add_edge(vmap[source], vmap[target], {weight}, graph);

    do_the_thing(graph, vertex(1, graph));

    std::cout << "test003: done." << std::endl;
}

int main() { test003(); }

You might be interested in vertex names as well: Boost graph custom indexes use Dijkstra

As an aside, regarding "consistency" of descriptors, perhaps also see Iterator and Descriptor Stability/Invalidation

Thank you @sehe again! Won't blame auto-completion... just how silly I am... so cringe...

No worries. It happens. Hopefully some of the alternatives accelerate your experience with the BGL learning curve.
